# Builds are not running after the teamcity instance changed

Tags: build, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Hi I am Teamcity Developer.
Now i Have a task to move Teamcity instance to another server. 
So far i moved the instance to another one but i am having a problem with running the builds. 
You can see below the builds are in incompatible agents.

SNapshot of my builds in Build agent

[image]

Please can anyone suggest the way to get builds run on time.

Comment: Do you have jdk1.8 installed on incompatible agents? The [JDK variables are defined](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-DefiningJava-relatedEnvironmentVariables) when the JDK found. You can [manually define](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Project+and+Agent+Level+Build+Parameters#ProjectandAgentLevelBuildParameters-AgentLevelBuildParametersagentSpecific) these variable in <agent home>/conf/buildAgent.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Your JDK does not seems to be recognized.

You should ensure it has been properly installed on every targeted agent.

To visualize your `environment` settings, you can click on your agent, `Agent Parameters` and `Environment Variable` tab.

Inside the `C:\BuildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties` file you can declare new variables, like :

```
env.JDK_18=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.xxx\
```

And, once it has been done, restart your TeamCity Agent Service.